# How can I read nested data (hashmap) in Firebase RealTime Database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I follow with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eQC8NuaMkw) and save mutliple image to my firebase database :

[image]

Gallery is hashmap, how I Can read this data?

My POJO class :

```
public class Tasks {
String titletask, decriptiontask, datetask, keytask, imagetask;
HashMap<String,String> gallery;
```

When I try with this code :

```
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Tasks task = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Tasks.class);
            list.add(task);
        }
        adapter = new TasksAdapter(getActivity(),list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I have a error :

> Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Comment: How do you initialize `mRef`?

Comment: mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TaskBox");

Comment: That looks correct. In that case I'm pretty certain the problem is in the structure of your `gallery`. I answered below.

Comment: Yes, you have right, thank you. I have something like this : Map<String,GalleryItem> gallery = tasks.get(position).getGallery(); and this read whole data from gallery. I can display key and value, for example key: -M6doNe9UqYiqylvcv and value : GalleryItem@9900, but how I can get to ImgLink? Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field in your `Tasks` class:

```
HashMap<String,String> gallery;
```

Would translate to a JSON structure like this:

```
"gallery": {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

Since that is not the structure you have, the mapping will fail.

---

To describe you JSON you'll either need to define a class for each gallery item:

```
public class GalleryItem {
  public String ImgLink;
}
```

And then:

```
HashMap<String,GalleryItem> gallery;
```

---

Alternatively you may be able to get away with `Object`:

```
HashMap<String,Object> gallery;
```

And (if this indeed works) treat the values in the `gallery` map as `Map<String, String>` themselves.